# What is an elegant way to call a method until it returns true?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'd like to call a method (and only call that method) until it returns true:

```
boolean done = false;
while(!done){
done = doStuff() // Returns boolean
}
```

Comment: `while(doStuff());` is also options. But I would seriously question such a design. Why does method `doStuff()` not loop until its return-value is `true`? Why should this method then have a return value at all? This very much sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Unfortunately opinion based questions aren't allowed on stack overflow.

Comment: Will usually lead to a compiler warning for an empty body. Maybe there's something better.

Comment: The Method does not loop cause it works in a synchronized section. I guess putting the thread to sleep would be an option.

Comment: What do you mean by "synchronized"? Do you mean synchronous?

Comment: *"Why does method doStuff() not loop until its return-value is true?"* I can think of lots of reasons/examples. Take a constraint satisfaction solver for example: if the `Solver` class has a `solve` method and the `Problem` interface has a `propagateConstraints` method, the `solve` method would like to repeatedly propagate constraints until no more work is done. Rather than require every `Problem` class to have its own loop, you can just make it return a `boolean` to indicate if it did anything or not.

Comment: I would probably use an executor service or some other thread based capability.

Comment: @WJS why? There's nothing here to indicate that any concurrency is required.

Comment: @ValentinMetz *"Will usually lead to a compiler warning for an empty body"* That warning can be prevented, e.g. in Eclipse it it prevented by adding a comment: `while (! doStuff()) {/*nothing to do*/}` --- The *"Undocumented empty block"* warning is documented as: *When enabled, the compiler will issue an error or a warning whenever it encounters an empty block statement **with no explaining comment**.*

Comment: There is nothing elegant about wasting energy by burning cpu cycles. You should have a variant function (i.e. a value that shows you make progress). `n = "number of items to process"; while (n != 0) { processItem(n - 1); n = n - 1; }`

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather opinionated question and will probably get closed, but if you'd like to be very verbose, you could do something such as:

```
boolean isItDone;
do {
    isItDone = doStuff();
} while (isItDone == false);
```